# Файлы  и папки

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы программа постоянно просматривала папку, а при появлении в нем файла загружала его, а после загрузки, файл удалялся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настроить слежение

```
private static void Track(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    // ...

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    watcher.Path = ".";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // ...
}
```

По событию создания файла загрузить и удалить его

```
private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    // TODO: загрузить и удалить файл по имени e.FullPath
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Компонент [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) Вам в помощь.